# Configure Domain per site in external sign-in using Sitecore federated authentication

Tags: federated-authentication

I have implemented external google signin using Sitecore federated authentication referring this [blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20220808172523/https://josedbaez.com/2018/03/sitecore9-sso/) .

Now I want to set domain based on website which the user browses. For Example, if the user browses website1 then the domain should domain1 . if it is website2 then the domain should be domain2.
How can I achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need, but with this example you can change the domain before redirecting: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/32900/3309